# Hosting secured connection with iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, ssl, gcdasyncsocket

I'm working on a file share application. It's working with TCP connection between two iOS devices and I need secured connection between them. I'm using GCDAsyncSocket library for connection. I used this library for connecting other applications that accepts SSL connection before so I have no problem with client side. Here is the question; how can I host a socket that only accept SSL connection with valid SSL certificate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my issue. In `didAcceptNewSocket` delegate method I load my certificate with these settings.

```
NSDictionary *settings = @{(NSString *)kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket:    [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain:       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates:       [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots:              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot:                   [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLCertificates:                    certificates,
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLIsServer:                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLLevel:                           (NSString *)kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1};
```